# Conditional Manifest File for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake, manifest

i'm stuck in a problem adding a manifest to a visual studio c++ project. The situation is that we have two different manifest description in Release and Debug. As we are changing the buildsystem to CMake, i need to include them configuration-specifically.

Currently i have for Release:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
   <dependency>
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='DeliveredComponent' version='1.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' />
     </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

And for Debug:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
   <dependency>
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='DeliveredComponent.Debug' version='1.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' />
     </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

Just do not ask why the Debug component is postfixed with **.Debug**. I can't change it.

Currently I'm adding the manifest with:

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET MyExeFile
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND "mt.exe" -manifest \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}\\MyExeFile.$(Configuration).x64.manifest\" -outputresource:\"$<TARGET_FILE:${targetname}>\;1\" 
    COMMENT "Adding manifest..."
)
```

This is deprecated starting with **CMake 3.4**, additionally this post-build step does alter the output file which implies **relinking the executable** afterwards (Visual Studio dependency check).

That is why I whould like to add the *.manifest to the **add_executable** command now (support since 3.4). But how can I switch the manifest?

Is there any possibility (using generator expressions or similar) to select one of two files to be compiled within the project? (DEBUG or RELEASE only). Or can I switch **internally in the manifest** between two paths? Something like

```
<dependentAssembly configuration='Debug'>
   ...
</dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to handle this. For now I'm compiling conditional pragmas into the application. This solves the problem for now.

```
#pragma once

#ifdef _DEBUG
# if defined _M_IX86
#  pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='MyLibrary.Debug' processorArchitecture='x86' version='1.0.0.0'\"")
# elif defined _M_IA64
#  pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='MyLibrary.Debug' processorArchitecture='ia64' version='1.0.0.0'\"")
# elif defined _M_X64
#  pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='MyLibrary.Debug' processorArchitecture='amd64' version='1.0.0.0'\"")
# else
#  pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='MyLibrary.Debug' processorArchitecture='*' version='1.0.0.0'\"")
# endif
#else
# if defined _M_IX86
#  pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='MyLibrary' processorArchitecture='x86' version='1.0.0.0'\"")
# elif defined _M_IA64
#  pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='MyLibrary' processorArchitecture='ia64' version='1.0.0.0'\"")
# elif defined _M_X64
#  pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='MyLibrary' processorArchitecture='amd64' version='1.0.0.0'\"")
# else
#  pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='MyLibrary' processorArchitecture='*' version='1.0.0.0'\"")
# endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by not adding it to the add_executable call but add if afterwards like so.

```
add_executable(myexe source1.cpp source2.cpp)
if (DEBUG)
  target_sources(myexe PRIVATE app.manifest.debug)
else ()
  target_sources(myexe PRIVATE app.manifest)
```

PRIVATE here means that the sources added are for this executable and not exported to any library that may depend on this. More information can be found in the documentation at
[cmake.org v3.6 docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/target_sources.html)

Comment: Pär, this is indeed true, but CMake is not able to generate a Visual Studio Project when Relesae and Debug differs.

Comment: Admittedly I didn't test this example so that could be the case, thought I had done something similar earlier but looks like I may be mistaken

Comment: An alternative would be to use generator expressions in the source list of `add_executable()`, i.e. `$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:app.debug.manifest>` and `$<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:Debug>>:app.manifest>`, since that would work reliably for all CMake generator types rather than relying on computing a `DEBUG` variable.