# Why does CMake add a manifest file self-assertively when using MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake, manifest

I need to embed a customized manifest file to my application. I'm using CMake with Ninja to build it, by MSVC 2019.

```
[build] cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Qt\Tools\CMake_64\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_exe --intdir=src\QSynthesis\WinMain\CMakeFiles\QSynthesis.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100190~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100190~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests src\QSynthesis\WinMain\app.manifest -- C:\PROGRA~2\MIB055~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1429~1.301\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo src\QSynthesis\WinMain\CMakeFiles\QSynthesis.dir\__\__\Common\WinMain\main.cpp.obj src\QSynthesis\WinMain\CMakeFiles\QSynthesis.dir\res.rc.res  /out:bin\QSynthesis.exe /implib:lib\QSynthesis.lib /pdb:bin\QSynthesis.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /manifest:no /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
[build] LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MIB055~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1429~1.301\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo src\QSynthesis\WinMain\CMakeFiles\QSynthesis.dir\__\__\Common\WinMain\main.cpp.obj src\QSynthesis\WinMain\CMakeFiles\QSynthesis.dir\res.rc.res /out:bin\QSynthesis.exe /implib:lib\QSynthesis.lib /pdb:bin\QSynthesis.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /manifest:no /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib src\QSynthesis\WinMain\CMakeFiles\QSynthesis.dir/manifest.res"
```

Then returns the error `CVTRES : fatal error CVT1100` due to duplicated resource of MANIFEST.

Where does `src\QSynthesis\WinMain\CMakeFiles\QSynthesis.dir/manifest.res` come from? I suppose it's the compiled object of `intermediate.manifest` generated by CMake. How to get rid of it?

Comment: This may help: [https://github.com/KDAB/GammaRay/issues/458](https://github.com/KDAB/GammaRay/issues/458)

Comment: I tried this but the problem still exists.

Comment: Maybe this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923420/conditional-manifest-file-for-visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923420/conditional-manifest-file-for-visual-studio)